# Need a method to prevent WP from adding <br> in between my shortcodes

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have tried out a few things to remove the `<br>` being created in between shortcodes, I found one in another thread, it looked promising, but it didn't work out:

```
function the_content_filter($content) {
    $block = join("|",array("category_product_list", "category_products"));
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[($block)(\s[^\]]+)?\](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[$2$3]",$content);
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[\/($block)](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[/$2]",$rep);
return $rep;
}
add_filter("the_content", "the_content_filter");
```

I was reading that wpautop could do the trick but nothing is working for me. Do I need to modify my actual shortcode somehow?

Here's one of the shortcodes I'm working with:

```
function category_product_list( $atts ) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'category'      => '',
        'per_page'  => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc'
    ), $atts));

    $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( esc_attr($category) ),
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   =>  'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order,
        'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query,
        'tax_query'   => $tax_query
    );

    $products = new WP_Query( $args );


    if ( $products->have_posts() ) :

        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($products->post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "all"));
        $first_term = $term_list[0];
        $first_term_name = $first_term->name;
        $url = get_permalink();
        $id = $products->post->ID;

        // $html_out = '<h2>Courses</h2>';

        $html_out = '<ul class="simple-sitemap-courses">';

            $html_out .= '<li class="page-item page-item-' . $id . '"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $first_term_name . '</a>';

                $html_out .= '<ul class="children">';

                while ($products->have_posts()) :   
                    $products->the_post();  
                    $product = get_product( $products->post->ID );

                    $course_title = get_the_title();
                    $url = get_permalink();
                    $id = $products->post->ID;

                    // Output product information here

                    $html_out .= '<li class="page-item page-item-' . $id . '"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $course_title . '</a></li>';

                endwhile;

                $html_out .= '</ul>';

            $html_out .= '</li>';

        $html_out .= '</ul>';

    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No Courses Found.";
    endif; 

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $html_out;
}
add_shortcode( 'category_product_list', 'category_product_list' );
```

Comment: Maybe there is a reason to modify your shortcode, but we can't see it in your question.

Comment: @MaxYudin added it to my OP.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple shortcode and added it two times to a page like so:

```
[my-shortcode]something[/my-shortcode]
[my-shortcode]else[/my-shortcode]
```

As you can see, I added a line break (`<br />`) after the first shortcode. So in the frontend it is also shown like this:

```
something
else
```

And in the HTML:

```
<span>something</span>
<br />
<span>else</span>
```

Than I also used the `the_content` filter but with `strtr()` like this:

```
    function remove_br_from_shortcodes($content){

        // look for the string "]<br />" and replace it just with "]"
        $replace = array (
            ']<br />' => ']'
        );
        $content = strtr($content, $replace);

        return $content;

    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'remove_br_from_shortcodes');
```

After refreshing the page, the frontend now shows:

```
something else
```

In the HTML:

```
<span>something</span>
<span>else</span>
```

As the name of `the_content` filter already suggests, it is a filter for the *normal post/page content*, not, for example text-widgets or excerpts.

If you also want to remove paragraphs (`<p>`) than please try adding this in the `$replace` array: (watch your comma´s!)

```
'<p>[' => '[',
']</p>' => ']',
```

With the PHP `strtr()` function, you can replace certain characters in a string. [More to read here.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtr.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the shortcodes in `<div>`  or `<span>` tags, if that's an option.